# javascript regex for xml/html attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

I cant seem to be able to build a good regex expression (in javascript) that extracts each attribute from an xml node. For example,

```
<Node attribute="one" attribute2="two" n="nth"></node>
```

I need an express to give me an array of

```
['attribute="one"', 'attribute2="two"' ,'n="nth"']
```

...
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Time for the [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an XML parser library?

Comment: @jfriend00 - probably because browsers have a built–in XML parser and suitable DOM methods already.

Comment: I'm not sure i want the overhead of an xml parser library, plus i'm rarely ever going to have well formed xml. im actual parsing the diff generated by git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this~

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myregexp = /<node((\s+\w+=\"[^\"]+\")+)><\/node>/im;
    var match = myregexp.exec("<Node attribute=\"one\" attribute2=\"two\" n=\"nth\"></node>");
    if (match != null) {
    result = match[1].trim();
    var arrayAttrs = result.split(/\s+/);
    alert(arrayAttrs);}
  </script>
```

Comment: I got about this far as well. unfortunately, a space in the attribute value breaks this.  Perhaps I need to first replace spaces in between "" with an underscore, then after i split the array, return back to spaces?

Answer (score 4):

In case you missed  Kerrek's comment:

#### you can't parse XML with a regular expression.

And the link: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

You can get the attributes of a node by iterating over its attributes property:

```
function getAttributes(el) {
  var r = [];
  var a, atts = el.attributes;

  for (var i=0, iLen=atts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    a = atts[i];
    r.push(a.name + ': ' + a.value);
  }
  alert(r.join('\n'));
}
```

Of course you probably want to do somethig other than just put them in an alert.

Here is an article on MDN that includes links to relevant standards:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.attributes

Comment: I'd definitely use this instead of a regex if possible +1

Answer (score 0):

The regex is `/\w+=".+"/g` (note the `g` of **global**).

You might try it right now on your firebug / chrome console by doing:

```
var matches = '<Node attribute="one" attribute2="two" n="nth"></node>'.match(/\w+="\w+"/g)
```

Comment: And if an attribute value has a space it fails. See the link in the first comment.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The question was "*a good regex expression ... that extracts each attribute from an xml node*", not one for the very limited example.

Comment: @Pablo, maybe you should try it before saying that you fixed anything. ;-)

Comment: @Qtax, oops, left the escape there. Thanks for the correction man :)

Comment: @Pablo, you should still try it, even on your limited example. ;-)

Comment: I didn't change the example (which works) but just the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get it using the following.  You would want the second and third matching group.

```
<[\w\d\-_]+\s+(([\w\d\-_]+)="(.*?)")*>
```

Comment: That won't work in a number of cases, such as if there's a namespace, e.g. `<ns1:tagname .... >`, or an attribute name contains a colon (:) or a period (.) character (not included in the appropriate part of the regular expression) or the value contains a double quote character.